# Send copy of email to BC email using Using mail() in php

Tags: php, phpmailer

If the clients email id is fatched using below code.

```
$message .= 'Email: '.$_POST['email']. "\n\r";
```

I guess `$email` is variable for client's email id. How do I send an email as BC to the client's email id?

Right now I am using only single email id using

```
$to = 'emailid@domain.com';
```

**Update:**
The email field value is `<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>` in the form.

**Update:** I have pasted entire code at http://pastebin.com/5bWDQSk2

Comment: If you are using PHPMailer, why don't you read the documentation? http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running at least 4.3, you can set a Bcc additional header. PHP will interpret this internally before sending the message.

```
$headers = "Bcc: address@place.com\r\nFrom: me@place.com"; // etc
mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

See the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Also note that because PHP doesn't expand escape sequences (\r, \n) when using single quotes, you must use double quotes for this string.

Comment: I tried your suggestion as well but it didnt work. Though the emails are getting delivered to `$to = 'emailid@domain.com';`

Comment: Please post your exact (relevant) code in the question. Can't debug without seeing it

Comment: I have updated my question with the link to the code.

Comment: @KevinS You're combining headers wrong; they all have to be the same string (the one you have From in). Right now, your `"Bcc:$email"` is being sent as an additional_parameter instead of an additional_header. Only your From is being sent as a proper header; put the Bcc in with that. Also I'd suggest adding some level of escaping here; letting the user arbitrarily add content to email headers could result in your server being repurposed to blast spam by hackers (and you also have a lot of SQL injection vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add custom headers:

```
# bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

mail('recipient@host.com', 'Subject', 'Message', 'Bcc: emailid@domain.com' )
```

Comment: I tried `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, 'Bcc:$email');` but it is not working

Comment: @KevinS you need the space, and that string *is* the header (you're passing too many parameters). Also depending on your config you may need to specify the from header too, like in my answer

Comment: Also variable substitution doesn't apply in single quotes, you need to use double or concatenate it manually.

Comment: @svoop I tried your suggestion but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `BCC` as a header e.g.

```
$header = "Bcc: john.doe@yahoo.com";
```

Comment: didn't work. though the emails are getting delivered to `$to = 'emailid@domain.com';`

Comment: TO be clear, was the email received in the BCC address' mailbox?